# how can I keep a user looged in even after page reload in nextjs app with firebase authentication?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

I am using firebase for authentication, the user is getting logged in with GoogleAuthProvider. The problem I am facing is the user is getting logged out on page reload. How can I persist a user with storing any credentials in localStorage.

below is the code I have tried but by storing access token in localStorage.

//signIn.tsx
`

```js
import styles from "../styles/styles.module.css";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Head from "next/head";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import { auth } from "../auth/auth";
import Image from "next/image";
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";

const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const signIn = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  router.asPath === "/";
  const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then(async (result) => {
        window.localStorage.setItem(
          "accessToken",
          await result.user.getIdToken()
        );
        router.push("/");
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        console.log("signin canceled by the user");
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Travelogue | SignIn</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Login" />
      </Head>
      <main className={styles.login_box}>
        <div>
          <h1
            style={{
              fontFamily: "sans-serif",
              fontWeight: "lighter",
            }}
          >
            Sign In To Travelogue
          </h1>
          <hr />
        </div>

        <div style={{ padding: "0 0 0 30px" }}>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            onClick={signInWithGoogle}
            className={styles.google_btn}
          >
            <div className={styles.googleSignIn_logo}>
              <Image
                alt="googleLogo"
                src={"/googleLogo.png"}
                layout="fixed"
                width={"30"}
                height={"30"}
                priority={true}
              />
            </div>

            <div className={styles.btn_text}>
              <p>
                <b>Sign in with google</b>
              </p>
            </div>
          </Button>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export default signIn;
```

`

//auth.tsx
`

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import configuration from "../Environment.config";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: configuration.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
  authDomain: configuration.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: configuration.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: configuration.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: configuration.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: configuration.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

`

//authorisation.tsx
`

```js
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../auth/auth";

//isLoggedIn is used to change the header
//isLoggedIn is always returning true (to be fixed)
//we need to have something like if ACCESS_TOKEN || accessToken is null return false
export const isLoggedIn = () => {
  if (
    //For ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
      if (user !== null && typeof window !== undefined) {
        const ACCESS_TOKEN = await user.getIdToken();
        const accessToken = window.localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
        if (
          accessToken !== null &&
          ACCESS_TOKEN !== null &&
          accessToken === ACCESS_TOKEN
        )
          return true;
      } else return false;
    })
  )
    return true;
};
```

`

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by setting up a service worker as documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/service-worker-sessions

I achieved this in a Nuxt app by implementing the Nuxt Firebase plugin. For Next, you could get some inspiration by looking at their repo: https://github.com/nuxt-community/firebase-module/tree/master/packages/firebase-module/lib/utils

Cheers